# "have to" or "must"

Tags: differences

I am trying to teach the difference between the use *have to* or *must*. But my students do not understand anything. Could you help me?

Comment: Alice, thank you for your salutations, but you might be interested in our new proposal designed specifically for those who want to learn the English language: English Language Learners (ell.stackexchange.com). On EL&U this kind of questions are considered at best too basic and this might explain the reason why you have already got two downvotes, but on ELL they are welcome. Please, take a look now or, however, be aware that that proposal exists. Thank you again.

Answer (score 6):

***Must*** and ***have to*** are synonymous, though some may prefer one or the other for certain purposes; this always happens with periphrastic modals, but these are merely individual preferences, not usage guides -- there is no consensus.

*Must*, as everyone knows, is a [modal auxiliary verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html).
One of the many peculiarities of such [modals](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf) is that they only have one uninflected form, with
 - no past tense form (so you can't say **Yesterday I musted do that*)
 - no infinitive form (so you can't say **Yesterday I didn't must do that*, either)
 - no gerund form (so you can't say **He hates musting do that*)

So, when one needs to say things like these -- these are ungrammatical, but not unmeaningful, after all -- one uses a periphrastic modal construction. Most modals have standard paraphrases that can be used in past and participial forms (*be able to* for alethic *can*, *be allowed to* for deontic *may*, *ought to* for *should*, etc).

The standard paraphrase for *must* turns out to be *have to*. Not only that, but there's a special pronunciation. This modal sense of the present tense phrases *have to* and *has to*
are **not** pronounced /hæv tu/ and /hæz tu/
but rather /'hæftu/ and /'hæstu/
or, most likely, /'hæftə/ and /'hæstə/.
**Always** with a voiceless /ft/ or /st/ cluster, **never** with a /v/ or a /z/.
Quite irregular, like a modal.
Furthermore, any form of *have to* has to be followed by an infinitive phrase, just like a real modal.

So what you **can** say instead of the starred sentences above is
 - *Yesterday I had to do that* (/'hædtə/, past tense)
 - *Yesterday I didn't have to do that* (/'hæftə/, infinitive)
 - *He hates having to do that* (/'hævɪŋtə/, gerund)

But there's no meaning difference between them.
  There are idioms, however, and that is sometimes enough.

Comment: Don’t forget *I’ll have to do that tomorrow* for **I’ll must do that tomorrow*.

Comment: Something has to be left as an exercise for the student, nu?